# (PHP 7.2) Warning: Use of undefined constant object - assumed 'object'

Tags: php

I am getting this warning in PHP 7.2 that wasn't showing up in 5.6.

Warning:  Use of undefined constant object - assumed 'object'

Here's what my code looks like...

```
CLASS WPA_PAGE {

  VAR $obj_template = object;

  function build_content() {
     global $app;

     $this->obj_template = new wpa_custom_template();   <---Warning occurs Here.
  }
}
```

** Note that I have stripped out a lot of code for purposes of this post.

As you can see, I have declared **$this->obj_template** in the beginning of the class.  I have a lot of similar code to this that doesn't seem to be generating any sort of error.

Is there something wrong with my syntax here or do you think something that is unsetting the variable/object before I am instantiating it?

can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't in this line: `VAR $obj_template = object;`? This looks a lot like PHP 4. Time to update your code.

Comment: That is certainly possible.  The code is pretty old.   What is the correct way to declare an variable of type object?

Comment: Object should be a keyword so there is your error. I would define it as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with line `VAR $obj_template = object;`. It looks very old, like PHP4. To make it more modern please remove `VAR` keyword as it is obsolete. Second thing, please remove assigment, there is no such thing as `object` in the modern PHP. So your line should look like `public $obj_template;`. You need to add visibility to it like `public / protected / private`. Please read the manual here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php especially http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php